# Neo4j index faster than relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using Neo4j 3.2.3 inside a Docker instance. Need help interpreting the profiler.

Importing relational data into Neo4j.  Initially importing a status column as a relationship to the Respondent node (i.e. `(r:Respondent)-[:FROM]->(s:Status)` where status has a unique id corresponding to the status column in the flat file).  Respondent nodes have a property `visit_date` which is an integer YYYYMMDD.  Using Status as a relationship in:

```
MATCH (s:Status {id: 1})<-[:FROM]-(r:Respondent)
WHERE r.visit_date >= 20160101 and r.visit_date <= 20161231
RETURN COUNT(r)
```

first does a node seek by range on the Respondent node's `visit_date` property (yielding 101,057 DB hits identical to the number of respondents with status equal to 1).  There is an index on the 'visit_date' property.  Next Neo4j expands all against the Status.  This expansion does 303,168 db hits equal to the number of all respondents and a filter is applied to each.  Would have expected that the number of hits would be lower than the first range seek instead Neo4j fans out.

If I put the status as a property in Respondent and query:

```
MATCH (r:Respondent)
WHERE r.visit_date >= 20160101 and r.visit_date <= 20161231 and r.status =1
RETURN COUNT(r);
```

the range seek is done first on `visit_date` and then a filter applied status (just on the range of 101,057 respondents).  The query is faster and has less total db hits.

Surprised by the results in the profiler (in particular fan-out in the expand all after the Respondents have been ranged).  One caveat is that I am profiling on my laptop with DDR3 RAM limited to 8GB so there is only 4G dedicated to the Docker container and 3072M to the heap which doesn't leave much over for page caching (500 M).  The speed difference in querying might be due to a poor configuration but the profiling (i.e. expanding or not) shouldn't be effected by the Neo4j configuration.  The question is why the fan-out when Status is a relationship when the range seek already has reduced the result set?

## Update 1 (with explain images)

Adds explain images (note: couldn't figure out how people dump explains/profiles as text).  Weird that the index hint on Status when it is a relationship is just as fast despite the actual hits being higher.

Matching Status relationship [image: Matching Status relationship]

Indexing status as property of Respondent[image: Indexing status property of Respondent]

Matching Status relationship using index hint which is just as fast as indexing on status as a property[image: Matching Status relationship with index Hint]

Comment: Using the status kind as a label has the same profile and speed as status as a property (i.e. no fan-out).

Comment: can you share with us the query explain ?